# How to debug a lambda expression using jdb

Tags: java, debugging, lambda, jdb

I am facing a problem in a clustered production server, I manage to isolate a single instance from users, so I have it available for debugging, I am doing this using jdb. Long intro end. My problem is that I need to debug the code into a lambda expression

```
public void method(){
    this.privateField = Util.methodCall(); // Here the breakpoint works
    Clazz.staticMethod(() -> {
       Integer x = 1;
       Long y = 2; 
       y = x * y; // I need a Break point here
       /* 
         And a lot of non related code
       */
       });
}
```

When I create the breakpoint in jdb in that line, it simply ignores my break point. I am pretty sure that the method is called because the breakpoint reach the first line of the method, but simply ignores the other, I am using `next` and `step` commands, but doesn't work. So what could be wrong with my process ? how to debug lambda expressions with jdb ?

Comment: Do you know the line number? You could try doing "stop at MyClass:22" where 22 is the line number and MyClass is the thing that contains the method and its lambda expression.

Comment: yes I that was the way I tried, but stills ignoring me, I am thinking now, that this is probably a problem with the `staticMethod` or with the lambda on it

Comment: What type is expected by `Clazz.staticMethod(..)`?

Comment: I don't remember, probably a `Callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an answer for people landing here and are intersted in.

**create the class**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
public class Clazz {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Clazz().method();
    }

    public void method() throws Exception {
        Clazz.staticMethod(() -> {
            Integer x = 1;
            Long y = 2L;
            y = x * y; // I need a Break point here
            return y;
        });
    }

    private static void staticMethod(Callable i) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("i = " + i.call());
    }
}
```

compile it

```
javac Clazz.java
```

start jdb for this class

```
jdb Clazz
Initializing jdb ...
```

set a breakpoint in the main method using `stop`

```
> stop in Clazz.main
Deferring breakpoint Clazz.main.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
```

start the debugging session with `run`

```
> run
run Clazz
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint Clazz.main

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Clazz.main(), line=6 bci=0
6            new Clazz().method();
```

Now the debugger is stopped in the main method, just before invoking `new Clazz().method();`.

To find the line we are interested in we `list` the source

```
main[1] list
2    
3    public class Clazz {
4    
5        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
6 =>         new Clazz().method();
7        }
8        
9        public void method() throws Exception {
10            Clazz.staticMethod(() -> {
11                Integer x = 1;
main[1] list 12
8        
9        public void method() throws Exception {
10            Clazz.staticMethod(() -> {
11                Integer x = 1;
12 =>             Long y = 2L;
13                y = x * y; // I need a Break point here
14                return y;
15            });
16        }
17
```

The command `list 12` is needed to list the following lines. In the output we can see that we want to stop at line `13`. So let's set a new breakpoint there with the `stop` command

```
main[1] stop at Clazz:13
Set breakpoint Clazz:13
```

to continue the execution till next breakpoint issue the command `cont`

```
main[1] cont
> 
Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Clazz.lambda$method$0(), line=13 bci=12
13                y = x * y; // I need a Break point here
```

we are not on line `13` and for example could `dump` the values of `x` and `y`.

```
main[1] dump x
 x = {
    MIN_VALUE: -2147483648
    MAX_VALUE: 2147483647
    TYPE: instance of java.lang.Class(reflected class=int, id=568)
    digits: instance of char[36] (id=569)
    DigitTens: instance of char[100] (id=570)
    DigitOnes: instance of char[100] (id=571)
    sizeTable: instance of int[10] (id=572)
    value: 1
    SIZE: 32
    BYTES: 4
    serialVersionUID: 1360826667806852920
    java.lang.Number.serialVersionUID: -8742448824652078965
}
main[1] dump y
 y = {
    MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808
    MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854775807
    TYPE: instance of java.lang.Class(reflected class=long, id=574)
    value: 2
    SIZE: 64
    BYTES: 8
    serialVersionUID: 4290774380558885855
    java.lang.Number.serialVersionUID: -8742448824652078965
}
```

going one `step` further

```
main[1] step
> 
Step completed: "thread=main", Clazz.lambda$method$0(), line=14 bci=26
14
```

we could now `dump` again the value of `y`

```
main[1] dump y
 y = {
    MIN_VALUE: -9223372036854775808
    MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854775807
    TYPE: instance of java.lang.Class(reflected class=long, id=574)
    value: 2
    SIZE: 64
    BYTES: 8
    serialVersionUID: 4290774380558885855
    java.lang.Number.serialVersionUID: -8742448824652078965
}
```

Comment: thank you, sadly I have no more the instance of problem, but the answer is quite the one i needed. But quick question about it,  your compiler adds by default the `-g` parameter right ? in other way the dump won't be able to reference `x` and `y` ?

Comment: @carpinchosaurio You are right. If the source is compiled without debug information you cannot dump the variables. Even you can step through the instructions using `stepi` you could not dump the variable nor the operant stack.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the answer. I need to debug Kotlin code using jdb, and cannot set break point inside lambda expressions. Will try your way and report the result

Comment: Update: jdb reports "xxx.kt source file not found", will try specifying kt source location

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the last time jdb got some love was in [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html)...

**Alternative**: IntelliJ supports this feature (breakpoint inside a lambda expression)